# How to populate a WPF multi column TreeView programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I am quite new to `WPF` and I spent the last few hours trying to add a `TreeView` which items contain multiple columns. I've looked on the internet for similar solutions, and I think that my problem is exactly the same, as explained in this answer: [How to bind WPF TreeView to a List programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481182/1699611) However, it seems like I can't resolve it, so I thought to ask for help.

Here is the code that I have in `XAML`:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1">
     <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding carModel}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding carHorsePower}" />
                </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And this is the `C#` code behind:

```
CarDealer carDealer = GetDealerCars(); 

foreach(var groupedCar in carDealer.cars.GroupBy(x => x.carBrand).ToList())
{
    TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
    item.Header = groupedCar.Key; // This works fine, it shows the brands in the tree view
    item.ItemsSource = groupedCar; // This is not shown properly, because I am not sure how to bind the carModel and the carHorsePower properties from the list

    treeView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The `CarDealer` class looks like that:

```
public class CarDealer
{
    public string dealerAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Cars> cars { get; set;}
}

public class Cars
{
    public string carBrand { get; set; }
    public string carModel { get; set; }
    public string carHorsePower { get; set; }
}
```

For now, the tree view is shown, with the headers, but I am not sure how to add the multiple columns, and instead of the columns, now it just shows `MyTestWpfApplication.Cars`, as in the link above. I think I have to create text blocks and bind the data from my `List<Cars>` to them.

EDIT: What I am trying to achieve is something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find out how to do it and since I didn't have more time, I decided to go with a `ListView` and a `GridView`, which was actually easier to achieve.

To anyone else, who is trying to do the same, this is a good tutorial to start with: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/

Answer (score 1):

Modify your xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="subItems">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding carModel}" />
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding carHorsePower}" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0" Background="Bisque" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TreeView Name="treeView1" Loaded="treeView1_Loaded">
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

Then modify your c# code:

```
 CarDealer carDealer = GetDealerCars();

 foreach (var groupedCar in carDealer.cars.GroupBy(x => x.carBrand).ToList())
 {
     TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
     item.Header = groupedCar.Key; 
     var src = new List<Cars>(groupedCar);
     item.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("subItems");
     item.ItemsSource = src;

      treeView1.Items.Add(item);
 }
```

But then again, if you invest more time in converting your project in MVVM, with templates, etc.. this will be better.

Comment: This seems to work, but now the headers are not shown, any ideas how to add them?

Comment: Can you add to your question above the visuals that you are trying to achieve? You are using Treeview and items are now shown with 2 columns -- that's the header right there. Do you mean, you need another item and the 2 columns should be the sub-Items?

Comment: I've added a picture of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, that I need to have another header and the two columns should be sub-items.

Comment: Answer is updated. Well, the term subitems in the context of treeview maybe is not appropriate. SubItems means you need to drill it down before showing it. In your screen shot, no further drill down is needed.